# Understanding the explanation Purcell provide for explaining why outside charge distribution is uniform in case of charge inside a spherical conductor

Tags: electrostatics

Let there be a point charge and a conducting sphere. If the point charge is inside, may be or may be not at the centre. Purcell explains why the outer surface is having a uniform distribution of charge using the superposition:

> That is, first removing the induced charge outside, and giving the reason that now the system charges: the induced inside one and the point charge will have electric field outside to be zero all over, outside of the sphere. So, when we slowly bring back the induced outside charge to this configuration, they don't feel any field from the other charges, hence they distribute uniformly.

- My query is, let's say some part of the induced outer charge is now there and we are adding the rest slowly. How are we sure that there is no change in the induced charge configuration, of the inside surface at all? Why does it keep remaining the same always, when slowly bringing back the induced $q$ charge, the outside one?

Comment: I had difficulty understanding the question, can you check it again to make sure you have written it correctly?

Comment: Yeah you edit is right thanks @BrendanDarrer